# Trying to figure out how to write an array out to a file stream in Android

Tags: android, file, stream

In my app on the simulator it takes like 20 secs to save a file 48k long.  Right now I'm saving byte by byte.  Using a file stream, FileOutputStream write function. 
Which looks like fos.write(cGlobals.board.BitMap[c++]);

I tried to do this but got a compile error saying invalid parm
fos.write(cGlobals.board.BitMap);
Is there a better way of doing this then byte by byte?
Ted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a BufferredOutputStream around your FileOutputStream

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(.....);
OutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream, 8192);
try {
   ... do your stuff using bos instead of fileOutputStream
} finally {
   bos.close();
}
```